# remove the div above

Tags: jquery, html, hide

i have a template that looks something like this.

## Sample Template

```
<div id="form-entry">
    <h4>Some heading here</h4>
    <div class="form-field">
        <label>Some Label</label>
        <input type="text" class="some_text" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-field">
        <label>Some Label</label>
        <input type="text" class="some_text" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-field">
        <label>Some Label</label>
        <input type="text" class="some_text" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-field">
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <label>Some Label</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-field">
        <label>Some Label</label>
        <textarea></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to remove (or hide) the `form-field` div above the div that contains `checkbox` input if a user checks the checkbox. The HTML is rendered automatically and do not have any specific `id's` or `classes`. How do i go about doing this. will jQuery position will be of any use?

## JS

```
$('.form-field input[type=checkbox]').click( function(){
    entity = $(this);
    dad = entity.parent(); // This gets the form-field div element that contains the checkbox
});
```

how do i capture the `form-field` div element above the `dad` element ?

Comment: Can't you add an id to the box before the checkbox one?
Sorry, just re-read your question. You say you can't

Comment: entity.parent().parent(); ?

Comment: as i metioned the template is rendered automatically, i really can't. I also forgot to mention i have a few similar `div.form-entry`'s on the same page as well

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('.form-field input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function(){
    if (this.checked) 
        $(this).closest('.form-field').prev().remove();
});
```

Removes the `.form_field` above the `.form_field` that contains the checkbox, if it's checked ?

Comment: No need to check if it's checked : if it changes from the initial (unchecked) state, it must be checked.

Comment: @dystroy - Yeah, you're probably right, and I did consider it, but the check does'nt matter, and shows how to check it should the inital state be changed to checked or something similar.

Comment: I'm not sure I like the last edit by gdoron. adeneo's version was fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
$('#form-entry input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
    $(this).parent().prev().remove();
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/RMRxC/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following jQuery:

```
$('.form-field input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().prev().toggle(); // parent is the checkboxs div, prev returns the previous element in the DOM
});​
```

`Toggle` will hide/show the previous div each time the checkbox is clicked.

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qH2KM/) that shows how this works

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.form-field input[type=checkbox]').click( function(){
    entity = $(this);
    dad = entity.parent().prev().remove(); // This gets the form-field div element that contains the checkbox
});
```